# Copying camera image in phonegap/cordova not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to save images i take with the camera on my phonegap app to a more permanent destination. I run the app on iOS and Android so i need this to work on ios and android.

So far i can get the image file name and temporary storage path. 
I can also get the base file system path for the device i am running (currently an Android Galaxy S7 edge). 
However, i am unable to move/copy the file from the temporary storage to the new one as it fails.
Ive got the following code and ive got a try/catch around the code which moves the images. in the catch i have an alert which triggers always as there is something wrong with my code.

Ive tried changing the moveTo to CopyTo and changing the code from output.moveTo to things like cordova.file.moveTo without success.
If anyone could help i would be greatful.
Thanks Kind regards

```
const tempFilename = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
const tempBaseFilesystemPath = imageURI.substr(0, imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
const newBaseFilesystemPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
var output=tempBaseFilesystemPath+tempFilename;
var saveOutput=newBaseFilesystemPath+tempFilename;
alert(tempFilename+","+tempBaseFilesystemPath+","+newBaseFilesystemPath+","+tempFilename);
try{
output.moveTo(tempBaseFilesystemPath, tempFilename, newBaseFilesystemPath,tempFilename)
      .then(function (success) {
          alert("done");
      }, function (error) {
              alert("not done");
      });
}
catch{
    alert("didnt run");
}
const storedPhoto = output;
localStorage.setItem('imageLoc',storedPhoto);
localStorage.setItem('goodPic','not');
    },
    function( message ) {
    },
     {
        quality: 30,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
     });     
    }
```

Comment: Hmm i still haven't figured this one out.

Comment: in particular its this line i think: output.moveTo(tempBaseFilesystemPath, tempFilename, newBaseFilesystemPath,tempFilename)

Comment: has anyone any ideas?